# How to find a list of ip addresses in another file

Tags: linux, bash

I was given the task to see if we are advertising a list of ip addresses(3000). Not a good idea to do it manually, so I copied all the ip addresses that we are advertising in a file. Now I just have to create a bash script and feed the list of ip address into the script so it can find the ip addresses in the file with the list of ip addresses being advertised. If found save it in one file if not in a different file. This is what I have so far. The problem with this script is that I have to type in manually every ip address. HOW CAN I FEED THE FILE WITH THE LIST OF IP ADDRESSES TO BE SEARCHED IN THE FILE WITH THE LIST OF IP ADDRESSES WE ARE ADVERTISING. Thank you very much in advanced.

```
 #!/bin/bash

while true; do
  echo -e "IP address: \c"
  read ip

  if grep --color "$ip" "ips"; then
    echo $ip "was found"
    echo $ip >> found
  else
    echo $ip "was NOT found"
    echo $ip >> notFound

  fi

done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better script :

```
while read ip  
do  
    grep "$ip"  "$ips" > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "$ip" >> ip.found || echo "$ip" >> ip.notfound  
done
```

Name the script "searchip.sh"
Assume your input file is "iplist" ,set up variable and call like this:

```
ips=ips
cat iplist | sh searchip.sh
```

or

```
sh searchip.sh < iplist
```

Then you get two files , one is ip found, other one is ip not found.
What you need is shell I/O redirection.

Comment: This will say that an IP is found if it's just a substring of one of the IPs in the list. Also, `.` has special meaning to `grep`, it's a wildcard character, and this can cause spurious matches. You should use `grep -F -x` to match whole lines without processing regular expression characters specially.

Answer (score 4):

If you sort the two files, you can use the [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) command:

```
sort all_ip_addresses > all_ip_addresses_sorted
sort adverted_ip_address > advertised_ip_address_unsorted

comm -23 all_ip_addresses_sorted advertised_ip_addresses_sorted
```

will show the IP addresses that are not advertised, and:

```
comm -12 all_ip_addresses_sorted advertised_ip_addresses_sorted
```

will show the advertised IP addresses.

You can also avoid creating the separate sorted files by using process substitution:

```
comm -23 <(sort all_ip_addresses) <(sort advertised_ip_addresses)
```

Comment: +1: Elegant! @Barmar: Good place for process substitution? `comm -12 <(sort all_ip_addresses) <(sort advertised_ip_addresses)`

Comment: Yes, I've used that idiom many times. But I don't think it's necessary for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ script < list_of_ip_addresses
```

That's all you need.