# Bash script that scans for unknown IP addresses and prints them

Tags: bash, ip

Is there a way to make a script that scans other scripts for IPs and prints them?

Example:

There is a file called Connect_IP.sh which is a code that connects your pc with the 123.456.XX.XX

If I scan this file with the scanner script I want to print this IP and warns me that this script includes commands that contain IP address

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find a list of ip addresses in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197744/how-to-find-a-list-of-ip-addresses-in-another-file)

Comment: But if I understood correctly you have to know what IP you are looking for.
What I wanted is a scanner that scans if a file or files contain IPs in their code.
Thanks by the way :) 
This will be also useful ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `grep -EHn '(^|[^0-9])([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}([^0-9]|$)' *` isn't all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide concise, testable sample input/output.